# Turn pynput.keyboard.Key key to an ascii value

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard, pynput

For a project I'm working on I need to send keyboard keys pressed in one computer to another. I managed to find pynput and it works pretty well in detecting which key pressed or released. My problem is that if a not alphanumerical key is pressed it returns an object of the type pynput.keyboard.Key which I couldn't find any way to convert into ascii code. This is how a simple code to detect the use of a key looks like:

```
from pynput import keyboard


def on_press(key):
    print(['pressed', key])


def on_release(key):
    print(['released', key])


def detect_keyboard():
    keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release).start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    detect_keyboard()
    while True:
        pass
```

I would really like to know if there is a way to do so, and if not I would be happy for other ideas how to implement my goal.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that it would be tedious, but you could write a dictionary with the key references returning the ascii values. Eg:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key

AsciiKeys = {
    Key.backspace:8,
    Key.esc:27}
```

Then you would later be able to reference it to get the ascii values.
You will be able to find all of the current keys here: https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#pynput.keyboard.Key